# How to "genericize" this extension method?

Tags: c#, generics, c#-3.0, extension-methods

I have the following method that currently works on int? variables.  I'd like to extend it to any numeric nullable variables (e.g. decimal?, double?, etc...)

```
public static bool IsNullOrInvalid(this System.Nullable<int> source)
{
    return (source == null || source == -1);
}
```

How can I pull this off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tricky bit is working out what "invalid" means in each case. If "any value which is deemed less than the default for the data type" is okay, you could try:

```
public static bool IsNullOrNegative<T>(this T? source)
    where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{
    return source == null || source.Value.CompareTo(default(T)) < 0;
}
```

EDIT: As noted in comments, there's no "numeric" constraint - it will be valid to call this method on every value type which is comparable with itself, such as `DateTime`. There's no way of avoiding that - adding more constraints would probably reduce the set slightly, but not completely.

As for comparing with exactly -1, you'd need to be able to work out the value "-1" for every type. There's no generic way of doing that. You could *manually* build a `Dictionary<Type, object>` of "-1 for each type I'm interested in" but it would be pretty ugly.

If -1 is invalid, is -2 really valid? That seems odd to me.

Comment: +1 This is the answer to the question, but to be clear, as @AngryHacker specified nullable numeric types, there is no way to constrain a generic to only numeric types. So this extension method would work on Boolean, Byte and DateTime variables as well.

Comment: @AngryHacker: Given that there's no generic way of saying "what's -1 in the current type" it's pretty hard to represent that generically. You could pass the particular invalid value in, of course...

Comment: @AngryHacker because you can't lock generics to numeric types, you won't be able to compare to see if the value is -1.  For example, DateTime can not be -1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible because to make this generic, it has to be generic across all types and invalid is specific to the integer. If you just make overloads of that method (double, float, etc.), the compiler should figure out which one you want when you type

```
(0.0).IsNullOrValid()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not, to make that possible you would need

```
public static bool IsNullOrInvalid<T>(this System.Nullable<T> source) where T : Numeric
```

but there is no `Numeric` base class for numbers in c#.
The problem is `source == -1`, there is no common class or interface that works with `-1`.

you could break out the `-1`

```
public static bool IsNullOrInvalid<T>(this System.Nullable<T> source, T invalid)
    where T: struct, IEquatable<T>
{
    return (source == null || source.Value.Equals(invalid));
}
```

But then you need to call like this

```
int? foo = -1;
var isInvalid = foo.IsNullOrInvalid(-1);
```

Comment: I doubt that == will work in this case. I suspect you need to call Equals, ideally having a constraint for `IEquatable<T>` to avoid boxing.

Comment: @Jon, oops, now it compiles better